# AWS EC2からインターネットへのアクセス、インターネットからのアクセス不可

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpc

AWS上のEC2(東京リージョン)からインターネットへのアクセス、インターネットからのアクセスができません。
正確に言うと起動直後はアクセスできるのですが、15分ほど経つとアクセスできなくなります。
但し、EC2インスタンスに対するSSH(22)やEC2からのSSH(22)は安定してアクセスできます。
調査観点など教えていただけると助かります。

実施したのは以下となります。
・VPCを作成
・VPCにインターネットゲートウェイをアタッチ
・ルートテーブルには0.0.0.0/0をインタネットゲートウェイに設定
・ネットワークACLはインバウンド・アウトバウンド共に全てOK
・セキュリティグループはSSH(22),HTTP(80),HTTPS(443)のインバウンドOK、アウトバウンドは全てOK
(補足情報)
米国東部リージョンにて同じ設定を行ったEC2へのアクセス、そのEC2インスタンスからのアクセスは安定しています。

調査したのは以下です。
[起動直後]
`yum update`可能
ルートテーブル確認

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-10-0-0-1.ap- 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

ルートをトレース

```
# tracepath www.google.co.jp
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 9001
 1:  ip-10-0-0-1.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal           0.182ms pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
 7:  100.65.11.65                                          0.484ms
 8:  27.0.0.159                                            0.869ms
 9:  52.93.72.179                                         10.148ms asymm 14
10:  52.95.31.64                                           1.055ms asymm 13
11:  52.95.31.147                                          6.853ms asymm 13
12:  54.239.53.46                                         18.003ms asymm 14
13:  52.93.250.250                                        13.072ms asymm 16
14:  150.222.90.38                                         5.261ms asymm 19
15:  54.239.53.247                                         2.561ms asymm 18
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

フローログでは22だけでなく、80,443などもACCEPT

[起動 15分後]
`yum update`はタイムアウト
ルートテーブル確認

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-10-0-0-1.ap- 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

ルートをトレース

```
tracepath www.google.co.jp
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 9001
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 9001
     Resume: pmtu 9001
```

フローログでは22はACCEPTであるが、80,443などはREJECT

Comment: 問題の切り分けをさせてください。同じVPC内からは該当EC2へのポートへのアクセスはできますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。同じVPC内の別EC2からのアクセスは特に問題なく、時間の経過関係なくアクセスできております。

Comment: REJECTということは、セキュリティグループやACLが怪しいんですが、APIやCLIで動的に変更しているということは無いですかね？

Comment: 少なくとも意図的に変更するような実装はしておりません。クラウドインフラ側から怪しいパケットなどの判断によりシャットダウンされている可能性もあるということでしょうか。